# Pierdo formato de disco en solaris 11, luego de reiniciar

Tags: solaris

Al reiniciar un servidor solaris 11 (T5-2), pierdo toda la información de los discos, cuando los verifico con el comando "format" tienen su configuración inicial. Debo formatearlos nuevamente y crear los slices para trabajar. Esos slice los utilizo para asignarlos a un ldom y pierdo toda la información cuando reinicio el ldom principal (primary).

```
    NAME                  STATE      FLAGS   CONS    VCPU  MEMORY   UTIL  NORM  UPTIME
    primary               active     -n-cv-  UART    2     2G       0.7%  0.7%  40m
    ldm-servidor1         active     -n----  5060    4     64G      0.1%  0.1%  32m
    ldm-servidor2         active     -n----  5061    4     32G      0.3%  0.3%  40m
```

Comment: Un reinicio no debería afectar los discos, así que a) seguro se hace el formateo? Hay un reporte de bug en el que el format se cuelga [aquí](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Sun%20Microsystems/2233596_1.html). b) estás haciendo el format en el disco que es?

Comment: Los disco del primary no pierden el formato, cuando hago el format y se los asigno al ldom y reinicio el primary el ldom no arranca. Revisare el link.